# POS tagging in a text file

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I have a question. I want to apply POS tagging in a text file (file1.txt) which contains the following sentences:

Hello World.

How are you?

First I want to tokenize it and then use POS tagger. I know how to tokenize and tag words for a string. But I am not sure how to do it in a file. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Read the file, then you have a string you can tokenize and tag.

Comment: The output I am getting is: [('H' , 'NNP'), ('E','NNP')...I am trying to read word by word but its reading character by character in the entire file. WHY??

Comment: Because you didn't tokenize it. You'd have the same problem if you'd _actually_ done the same with a string.

Comment: Edit **your question** to show the code that's causing you the problem, and you'll most likely get quick help. That's how this site works. Ask a good (i.e. carefully written) question, get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is point your script to the folder (or more specifically, the path) where your file is located:

```
path = 'C:\Scripts\My_Scripts\file1.txt'
```

and then plug it into your code to open it and manipulate it as normal - like make everything lowercase, for example:

```
with open(path) as sample_text:
     for lines in sample_text:
          lowers = lines.lower()
```

Comment: That's a pretty terrible way to read a file for POS tagging. You read line by line, but sentences cross line boundaries.